# Connection refused at port 80 MacOS Ventura 13

Tags: mac

Can someone assist on how to open port 80 for connections, I get a connection refused: See below

MacBook-Pro:bin say$ telnet localhost 80

Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585116/the-port-80-in-mac-is-used) you get some reference.